# Will I run into any bugs using Loading Button mui from material-ui/lab with this list of dependences?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

````
``` "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.44",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.6",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.8",
    "@mui/material-next": "^6.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.17.5",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "joi": "^17.6.2",
    "joi-browser": "^13.4.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },```
````

I believe I found a hacky way of being able to use the loading button mui component from material-ui/lab. Is there a better way to download the necessary dependencies than what I have here? Will this run into any serious bugs down the road when I employ the loading button component? I used --legacy-peer-deps for @material-ui/lab@next. Will this break anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 5, You should use `npm install @mui/...` instead of `npm install @material-ui/...` that is for versions up to 4.
This way the problem with `--legacy-peer-deps` will be resolved.
So for the `LoadingButton` case, easily run `npm install @mui/lab`, and in Your code import it like
`import { LoadingButton } from '@mui/lab';`

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need from material ui is provided with this npm install:

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

Comment: So when I use this import

import LoadingButton from '@mui/lab/LoadingButton';

It throws this error: 

ERROR in ./src/styles/loadingButton.js 5:0-55

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/emotion/LoadingButton' in 'C:\src\vg-flexV2\src\styles'

https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.10.9/docs/data/material/components/buttons/LoadingButtons.js

This import comes straight from the github source code? How do I resolve this with only material, emotion react, and emotion styled dependencies?